# WSO2 - Gateway Token Cache not working

Tags: api, caching, wso2

We are using WSO2 to access some of our services. WSO2 also handles authentication. 
We are facing a problem with this authentication though. When we do a request for a token we get an active token which is about to expire (let's say 1 second left). Call is:

```
Call: https://url.com/token
Header: Authorization - Basic Wm5VR1pDTGtVbjRyZllQOHVQVDJSUVRFeGFRYTpSMDVaQWZUNThDbWJxSW96d3NBSGdadmFVSzRh
Result:
{
  "access_token": "8b8243fa-4f74-363f-ab83-8a5752ccb3d3",
  "scope": "am_application_scope default",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 1
}
```

A few seconds later we make a call to one of our API's which returns an authorization error as the token has expired. We then request a new one which works fine.

However upon reading up on the gateway token cache the token should be cached for 15 minutes by default. I checked our config file and the settings are indeed correct:

```
<CacheConfigurations>
        <!-- Enable/Disable token caching at the Gateway-->
    <EnableGatewayTokenCache>true</EnableGatewayTokenCache>
        <!-- Enable/Disable API resource caching at the Gateway-->
    <EnableGatewayResourceCache>true</EnableGatewayResourceCache>
    <!-- Enable/Disable API key validation information caching at key-management server -->
    <EnableKeyManagerTokenCache>false</EnableKeyManagerTokenCache>
    <!-- This parameter specifies whether Recently Added APIs will be loaded from the cache or not.
         If there are multiple API modification during a short time period, better to disable cache. -->
    <EnableRecentlyAddedAPICache>false</EnableRecentlyAddedAPICache>
        <!-- JWT claims Cache expiry in seconds -->
    <!--JWTClaimCacheExpiry>900</JWTClaimCacheExpiry-->
    <!-- Expiry time for the apim key mgt validation info cache -->
    <!--TokenCacheExpiry>900</TokenCacheExpiry-->
    <!-- This parameter specifies the expiration time of the TagCache. TagCache will
         only be created when this element is uncommented. When the specified
         time duration gets elapsed ,tag cache will get re-generated. -->
    <!--TagCacheDuration>120000</TagCacheDuration-->
</CacheConfigurations>
```

So we ware expecting that the call should still be working after the expiry of the token.

We are using WSO2 API version 2.0.0.

Any other config I need to check?

Comment: Your expectation is actually a bug. It doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the statement: **"expires_in": 1**  So your token expires in 1 second.

> So we ware expecting that the call should still be working after the expiry of the token.

Nope, once the token expires, it will be removed from the cache as well (or - at least the cache won't return it)

The default token lifetime can be set set in the **identity.xml** config file, see [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens-changeDef)

Comment: OK, but how would you solve our problem then? When we try to get a new token we still get the same token that is not expired yet. Or can we force to get a new token?

Comment: now I see  what you mean. I ntheory - you can refresh a token using **grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=...** , though believe you'll get the refresh tokens only with certain grand types

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, we are trying that at the moment, but it seems that will do the trick!